# Rearranging elements

Tags: ruby, arrays

What is the easiest way to rearrange the elements of an array by referencing their indice? Something like this:

```
[:a, :b, :c, :d].rearrange(3, 1, 0, 2) # => [:d, :b, :a, :c]
[:a, :b, :c, :d].rearrange!(3, 1, 0, 2) # => [:d, :b, :a, :c]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, Ruby already has this method, only that it's called [values_at](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-values_at):

```
>> [:a, :b, :c, :d].values_at(3, 1, 0, 2)
=> [:d, :b, :a, :c]
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd turn it around a bit. A single permutation is just a function which maps an Array to another Array so this seems natural:

```
a = [:a, :b, :c, :d]
permuted = [3, 1, 0, 2].map { |i| a[i] }
```

That's easy to monkey patch into Array if necessary:

```
class Array
    def permute(*p)
        p.map { |i| self[i] }
    end
end
```

Error checking, `permute!`, and further niceties are left as an exercise.